# Speech Synthesizer in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text-to-speech

I am developing a program to identify mathematical formula from a printed document and read it out loud. For that I am using Visual Studio 2015 and C#, and for reading purpose am using Speech Synthesizer  in-build System.Speech assembly. But I am facing a problem that it doesn't identify "-" (minus mark). For example if I have A - B it reads only A and B letters. I have searched many online APIs too, but then again they also don't identify "-" (minus mark).

So can I have a way to read that "-" (minus marks) too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you can't simply replace it with the word "minus" before handing it off to SAPI?

Comment: of course I tried it too, but didn't work. I tried to identify the "-" in the given string using a for each and tried to replace. eg: string ss = ss.Replace("-","minus"); but didn't even identify that "-"

Comment: (ctd....) in the given string to replace the word "minus"

Comment: So maybe the "-" isn't a minus but is some other character than looks like a minus. Check the hex code for the character in your input see whether it's really a minus.